# How to preg_match specific bibles verses and retrieve the book, the chapter and verse in each case

Tags: php, regex

I have read many posts on SO about preg_matching Bible verses but none of them seems to meet my requirement. I am trying to match the **following verses with dot** all in one preg_match and retrieve the book name the chapter and the verse.

> Hebrews 11.6

> 2 Chronicles 10.16

> Romans 13.13

> 2 Kings 5.10

> 3 John 1.5

The verses above should respectfully output

I did

```
if (preg_match('/[ ]{0,}([0-9]{1}[ ]{0,}[a-zA-ZàâäæáãåāèéêëęėēîïīįíìôōøõóòöœùûüūúÿçćčńñÀÂÄÆÁÃÅĀÈÉÊËĘĖĒÎÏĪĮÍÌÔŌØÕÓÒÖŒÙÛÜŪÚŸÇĆČŃÑ]*)[ ]{0,}([0-9]{1,3})[ ]{0,}:[ ]{0,}([0-9]{1,3})[ ]{0,}/', $bible_passage, $ourmatches)) 
    {
        $book = $ourmatches[1];
        
        $chapter = $ourmatches[2];
        
        $verse = $ourmatches[3];
        echo "Book $book chapter  $chapter verse $verse ";

    }
```

This is able to match those verses but not able to retrieve each book separately with the verse. I want to get the following result

> Book Hebrews Chapter 11 verse 6

> Book **2 Chronicles** Chapter 10 verse 16

> Book Romans Chapter 13 verse 13

> Book **2 Kings** Chapter 5 verse 10

> Book **3 John** Chapter 1 verse 5

For Hebrews 11.6 what I get is Book 1 Chapter 1 verse 6 instead of Book Hebrews Chapter 1 verse 6

Please how to fix this?

Comment: Maybe you just need `^(.*?)\s*(\d+)\.(\d+)$`? See https://regex101.com/r/98KlWa/1 (see [sample code](https://regex101.com/r/98KlWa/1/codegen?language=php)).

Comment: Thanks but I did that but it outputs The result of the substitution is Hebrews 11.6 2 Chronicles 10.16 Romans 13.13 2 Kings 5.10 Book 3 John chapter 1 verse 5. I need to put each of the book in a variable and the chapter in a variable

Comment: So use it with preg_match_all instead then, that gives you the matched parts in an array structure. https://3v4l.org/irnBp

Comment: Please post that as an answer because it answers my question

Comment: @JohnMax That regex is already used in my answer. It is the regex from my top comment basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
<?php

$text = 'Hebrews 11.6
2 Chronicles 10.16
Romans 13.13
2 Kings 5.10
3 John 1.5';
if (preg_match_all('~^(.*?)\h*(\d+)\.(\d+)$~m', $text, $ms, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0)) {
    foreach ($ms as $m) {
        $book=$m[1];
        $chapter=$m[2];
        $verse=$m[3];
        echo "Book $book chapter $chapter verse $verse\n";
    }
}
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/RPOTE), and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/98KlWa/2).

Output:

```
Book Hebrews chapter 11 verse 6
Book 2 Chronicles chapter 10 verse 16
Book Romans chapter 13 verse 13
Book 2 Kings chapter 5 verse 10
Book 3 John chapter 1 verse 5
```

*Regex details*:

- `^` - start of a line (due to `m` flag)
- `(.*?)` - any text, as short as possible
- `\h*` - zero or more horizontal whites[ace
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits
- `\.` - a dot
- `(\d+)` - Group 3: one or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Very correct and thank you for explaining the regex.

Answer (score 2):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
<?php
$data = [
    "Hebrews 11.6",
    "2 Chronicles 10.16",
    "Romans 13.13",
    "2 Kings 5.10",
    "3 John 1.5",
];
array_walk($data, function($entry) {
    preg_match('/(?:(\d+)\s+)?(\w+)\s+(\d+)\.(\d+)/', $entry, $capture);
    list($volume, $book, $chapter, $verse) = array_slice($capture, 1);
    echo "Book $book " . ($volume ? "volume $volume " : "") . "chapter $chapter verse $verse\n";
});
```

The output is:

> Book Hebrews chapter 11 verse 6

> Book Chronicles volume 2 chapter 10 verse 16

> Book Romans chapter 13 verse 13

> Book Kings volume 2 chapter 5 verse 10

> Book John volume 3 chapter 1 verse 5